# Identify timer created in a list

Tags: java, android, timer

If I create a list of Timers in the following way:

```
timers = new ArrayList<Timer>();

for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Task of timer here                    


                }
            }, 0, 1000);

        timers.add(timer);
}
```

How I can identify inside the run() method what list item is?

If I do as follows does not work because I will be setting all the id of the last timer:

```
timers = new ArrayList<Timer>();

for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
        final int timerId = i;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

             @Override
             public void run() {

                //Task of timer here    
                 int id = timerId;


                    }
                }, 0, 1000);

        timers.add(timer);
}
```

Comment: You can make it work if you make timerId as final... final int timerId = i; Note because you make it final you cannot modify the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use a different data structure. IE: `Hashmap`, link a key (in your case, the ID) to a `Timer` object.

The Timer object can also take in a `String` in the constructor.

From javadoc:

> **Creates a new timer whose associated thread has the specified name.**

You would then execute the getName() method on the Thread in your runnable:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

Comment: If I create Timer with string in constructor, how can I access to name from run() method? Timer don´t have get methods.

Comment: It attaches a name to the Thread running the Timer. IE: Thread.currentThread().getName()

Answer (score 2):

```
final List<Timer> timers = new ArrayList<Timer>();

for(int i = 0; i<10;i++) {            
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

         @Override
         public void run() {

             //Task of timer here    
             int id = timers.indexOf(timer);


         }
    }, 0, 1000);    
    timers.add(timer);
}
```

Also good, because faster for a bigger number of timers would be a HashMap/HashTable:

```
final Map<Integer, Timer> timers = new Hashtable<Integer, Timer>();

for(int i = 0; i<1000;i++) {            
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

         @Override
         public void run() {

             //Task of timer here    
             int id = timer.hashCode();
             Timer t = timers.get(id);

         }
    }, 0, 1000);    
    timers.add(timer.hashCode(), timer);
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. This helped me a lot for solving a major issue in a app, running multiple dynamic timers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `TimerTask` and implement the functionality you are looking for

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    private int timerId;
    public MyTimerTask(int timerId){
        this.timerId = timerId;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {}
}
...
timers = new ArrayList<Timer>();

for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
        final int timerId = i;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(timerId), 0, 1000);

        timers.add(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create your custom timer task which can manage your id corresponding to timer task.

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

int id;
public MyTimerTask(int  id) {
    this.id = id;

}


@Override
public void run() {
System.out.println("Running task id:"+id);
}
```

}

And then

```
timers = new ArrayList<Timer>();
for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(i),0, 1000);

        timers.add(timer);
}
```

Hope this would help.